# Find a row with timestamp closest to the given time in datatable

Tags: c#

I have a datatable with a column named Timestamp and other columns. I'm trying to find those rows where the timestamps are nearest to the given times. For example, there are some rows with different timestamps. How can I find the rows which are closest to 12/02/2015 15:00:00, 12/02/2015 15:15:00, etc. In the following samples, rows with timestamp 12/02/2015 14:59:48.089 and 12/02/2015 15:16:01.376 are the most closed rows for the given time 12/02/2015 15:00:00 and 12/02/2015 15:15:00 respectively.

....

12/02/2015 14:57:59.768

12/02/2015 14:59:48.089

12/02/2015 15:00:59.453

12/02/2015 15:02:12.145

12/02/2015 15:10:35.789

12/02/2015 15:16:01.376

.......

I tried to use

```
DataRow[] drRows = dtMyRecords.Select("MIN(Timestamp-#12/02/2015 15:00:00#)");
```

or

```
object obj = dtStationRecords.Compute("MIN(Timestamp-'12/02/2015 15:15:00')", null);
```

to find it. But they don't work. Could you give solutions?

Comment: What's the type of the column?

Comment: @harmony here is a good link to look at http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/

Answer (score 1):

Broadly, you want to get the absolute value of the delta time (though don't try Chris's code, you can't call Math.Abs() on a TimeSpan). You'll probably have to parse the inputs first, e.g. using DateTime.Parse().

Here's some code to select the closest one. It uses mock data (`dates`), as I don't know what your DataSet looks like.

```
string[] dates = new[] { "12/02/2015 14:57:59.768", "12/02/2015 14:59:48.089" };
DateTime target = DateTime.Parse("12/02/2015 14:58:00");
var closest = dates
   .Select(date => new {
      date, distance = Math.Abs(DateTime.Parse(date)Ticks - target.Ticks)})
   .OrderBy(dt => dt.distance)
   .First().date;
```

Result:

`12/02/2015 14:57:59.768`

However, rather than implementing this yourself, why not have the database do this for you? Unless you're reusing the data, this will result in much smaller transactions and faster lookups.

```
DECLARE @target DateTime = '2015-05-05 12:15:00' --your query input
SELECT TOP 1 Timestamp 
FROM YourTable 
ORDER BY ABS( DATEDIFF( SS, Timestamp, @target ) ) 
-- "SS" above means second-level precision.
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to take the absolute difference between the timestamp in the database from your target time and take the smallest difference.

```
var result = data.Min(r = Math.Abs(r.Timestamp - targettime));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are looking for something like this:

```
DateTime target = new DateTime(2015,12,2,15,0,0);

var closest = dtMyRecords.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(drRow => drRow.Field<DateTime>("Timestamp"))
    .OrderBy(d => Math.Abs(d.Ticks - target.Ticks))
    .First();
```

This will work fine if this is not a performance-critical application, but the trouble with using `.OrderBy()` is you don't really need to reorder the elements. You need to enumerate your DataTable once and keep a record of the closest item.

An algorithm like the following is a bit uglier, but a bit more computationally efficient:

```
DateTime target = new DateTime(2015,12,2,15,0,0);

DateTime closest=DateTime.MinValue;
long closestTicks=long.MaxValue;

foreach(var d in dtMyRecords.AsEnumerable().Select(drRow=>drRow.Field<DateTime>("Timestamp")))
{
    long currentTicks = Math.Abs(d.Ticks - target.Ticks);
    if(currentTicks >= closestTicks) continue;
    closestTicks = currentTicks;
    closest = d;
}

// "closest" will now hold the closest date (or defaults if the sequence contains no elements)
```

Something similar (and, IMO, similarly ugly) could be accomplished with LINQ's `.Aggregate()` method. Unfortunately, LINQ doesn't give you a clean, efficient, out-of-the-box way to do what you need here, but, if you are interested, there is a library to look into, [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ), which provides a `MinBy()` extension method. Even if you choose not to use it, the [source code](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs) may inform the algorithm you decide to use.